# Different syntax for equivalent C-strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, null, character

```
char s[] = "hello world";
char s[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', 0};
```

Are these two lines of code equivalent in C++?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: These things[null terminated strings stored in char arrays] are called C-strings, even if they are used in C++.  C++ strings are of the type `std::string`, `std::wstring` or some other specialization of `std::basic_string<>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the first one initialises the array by copying from a string literal which is stored in static memory. The second, which is initialised from an array initialiser list, probably doesn't create anything in static memory, but generates instructions to move constant numbers (intrinsic to the instructions) into each position in the array.

Additionally, if two things are equal then applying the same transformation to them will also result in an equality. However, changing both to pointers instead of arrays (and adding const) will prevent the one with the initialiser list from compiling, so there they further differ.

Ignoring those differences, what you end up with in the array will be the same either way.

Comment: +1: verified for GCC 3.4.4 - the `{ ... }` approach generated `movb $104, -40(%ebp); movb $101, -39(%ebp)` etc copying character by character into the local buffer (whether without optimisation or at `-O3`).

Comment: Accepted answer and +1 for pointing out the difference between the literal in static memory and generated instructions.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Life's like that :-/.  But if you hadn't been downvoted, I wouldn't have bothered with my comment above.

Answer (score 3):

Yes they are equivalent, but it's C, not C++.

Comment: I mean the syntax in 'C' - either a C or C++ compiler would produce equivalent code. I didn't mean to get too nit-picky, but I've been downvoted for saying 'C++' when the example had only 'C' code.

Comment: @MarkStevens: The people who downvoted you were in the wrong.

Comment: FWIW, C and C++ do differ in one semi-related way though: C allows extra initializers, but C++ does not. For example, `char a[2] = "12";` is allowed in C (produces an array of two characters with no NUL terminator). C++ does not allow this -- if you specify a size for the array too small to hold the initializer (including NUL terminator), it's an error.

Answer (score 2):

If your forget about the fact that second is harder to write yes they are same!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much... yes. 
Both are mutable and terminated by a null character.

Except the first is terminated implicitly.